# How to fix SystemInvalidOperationException error?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

There is no error on my code and is working perfectly but if the form runs it pops a note stating 'The form referred to itself during construction from a default instance which led to infinite recursion. Within the form's constructor refer to the form using ME'. I know what the note meant but my code is from a CLASS how can I write ME.DataGridView1 in a class.

Here is the code:

```
Public Function billing_member_data_grid_radiobutton4_checkchanged()

    MysqlConn.ConnectionString = ServerString
    Dim dbDataSet As New DataTable
    Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim bSource As New BindingSource

    Try
        MysqlConn.Open()

        Dim query As String

        query = "SELECT user_memberid as 'Member ID',user_firstname as 'First Name',user_middlename as 'Middle Name',user_lastname as 'Last Name',user_birthday as 'Birthday',user_age as 'Age',user_address as 'Address',user_contact as 'Contact Number',user_gender as 'Gender' FROM gym.user"
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(query, MysqlConn)
        SDA.SelectCommand = COMMAND
        SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)
        bSource.DataSource = dbDataSet
        Billing_Member_Data_Grid.DataGridView1.DataSource = bSource
        SDA.Update(dbDataSet)

        MysqlConn.Close()


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()



    End Try
    Return True

End Function
```

Comment: Turn **Option Strict On**. Implement `Using`. Use **parameters**. Just a couple of pointers for you.

Comment: Elaborate `connect these two functions` in your context

Comment: Why are you using functions like subroutines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call READER.Close() after you are finished reading.

Comment: I cannot close it because what if im reading 5 datas and it will close after reading one

Comment: You have 2 different readers, one is declared in each method. You should close the first one when you are done reading and then the second one will be used in loadtrainer2(). You call READER.Close() after the "End If" which will ensure that any data present has already been read.